# Identifying Unary minus in calculator, java

Tags: java, tokenize

Hi guys
i'm almost done writing my code and i'm stuck with this stupid thing. I can identify cases in which there's a unary minus before brackets (-[4 + 4]). here's my code:

```
package oop.ex2.expression;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import oop.ex2.exception.*;
import oop.ex2.main.Tokenizer;

/**
 * This class contains 3 public static methods. All 3 methods are used
 * to parse text into a mathematical expression. The information is "thrown"
 * back and forth from one method to another.
 */
public class ExpressionParser {

    /**
     * This method uses expression() method to parse the text into mathematical
     * expressions, and returns an expression which is the sum of all
     * expressions returned from expression() [the sum is calculated according
     * to the right operator]
     *
     * @param st - the Tokenizer parsing the text
     * @return - Expression, the sum of all expressions from expression()
     * @throws InputException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Expression sumExpressions(Tokenizer st)
            throws InputException, IOException {
        boolean endOfLine = false;
        Expression temp = expression(st);
        int token = Tokenizer.TT_NOTHING;
        while (!endOfLine) {
            token = st.nextToken();
            if ((token == Tokenizer.TT_OPERATOR)
                    || (token == Tokenizer.TT_OVERLOADED_OP))
                temp = new FatherExpression(st.op, temp, expression(st));
            else
                endOfLine = true;
        }
        return temp;

    }

    public static Expression expression(Tokenizer st) throws InputException, IOException {
        Expression result = null;
        switch (st.nextToken()) {
            case Tokenizer.TT_NUMBER:
                result = new NumberExpression(st.nval);
                break;
            case Tokenizer.TT_VARIABLE:
                result = new VariableExpression(st.sval);
                break;
            case Tokenizer.TT_FUNC:
                result = createFunction(st);
                break;
            case '[':
                result = sumExpressions(st);
                if (st.ttype != ']')
                    throw new BracketException("BracketException: "
                            + "one too many ']'");
                break;
            default:
                throw new UnexpectedTokenException("Unexpected token on" +
                        "ExpressionParser.elements(st)");
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static Expression createFunction(Tokenizer st)
            throws IOException, InputException {
        if (InlineManager.getAllInlineFunctions().containsKey(st.sval)) {
            InlineFunction temp = InlineManager.getInlineFunction(st.sval);
            temp.setArguments(st);
            return temp;
        }
        if (st.sval.equals("MAX"))
            return new Max(st);
        if (st.sval.equals("MIN"))
            return new Min(st);
        if (st.sval.equals("POW"))
            return new Pow(st);
        if (st.sval.equals("MOD"))
            return new Mod(st);
        if (st.sval.equals("ABS"))
            return new Abs(st);
        throw new FunctionNameException("Wrong funcion entred " + st.sval);
    }

    public static HashMap<String, Expression> parseArguments(Tokenizer st)
            throws IOException, InputException {
        HashMap<String, Expression> result = new HashMap<String, Expression>();
        if (st.nextToken() != '{')
            throw new UnexpectedTokenException("Missing {");
        int argument = 0;
        while (true) {
            st.ignoreToken(',', true);
            switch (st.nextToken()) {
                case '}':
                    st.ignoreToken(',', false);
                    return result;
                case '[':
                    result.put(String.valueOf(argument++), sumExpressions(st));
                    break;
                case Tokenizer.TT_NUMBER:
                    result.put(String.valueOf(argument++), new NumberExpression(st.nval));
                    break;
                case Tokenizer.TT_VARIABLE:
                    result.put(String.valueOf(argument++), new VariableExpression(st.sval));
                    break;
                case Tokenizer.TT_FUNC:
                    result.put(String.valueOf(argument++), createFunction(st));
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new UnexpectedTokenException("Unexpected token on function arguments");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it long i know. Expression object could be a constant, a variable or a function such as MAX{3,2} which is 3. expression() uses a tokenizer i have built to parse text into an expression, and sumExpression() uses expression() to create a new Expression which is a combination of two Expression object according to the right operator.

i hope its clear. as i said before i can't figure out how to identify the unary minus (-[4] would be -4) thing. i didn't put my tokenizer code, didn't think its necessary.

thanks!

P.S.
the order of calculations is defined to be left to right with no regards to type of operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between (prefix) unary and (infix) binary operators is the context in which they occur. A binary operator always follows an expression, while a unary operator occurs at a position where an expression is expected, i.e. at the start, after an operator or after an opening parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Is "I *can* identify cases in which there's a unary minus" a typo?

It looks like if you hit "+", "-", "*", or "/" in `parseArguments`, you're immediately creating an instance of the `InlineFunction` class and passing the tokenizer as the argument to the constructor. The constructor assumes that the things on either side of the current token are the arguments to that operator, and doesn't know when "-" is actually supposed to be unary. Is that correct? Could you show us that constructor?

I would think that it would be pretty easy to tell when "-" is supposed to be parsed as a unary minus sign - it would be places where a binary operator isn't legal: at the beginning of a line or parentheses/etc.-delimited group, immediately after another operator, or at the beginning of an expression in a comma-delimited list (i.e. the beginning of an argument to your max, min, etc. functions).